# Prisma not performing update on record

Tags: prisma

There are a few things going on with Prisma `update` that I just don't get.

1. Why is the update (using the ORM way) not performed ?
2. Why the value of `data.address` seems to affect the outcome of the update ?
3. Do I have to provide all of the fields of the entity when updating ? Or in this case, could I just put what I want changed inside of `data` ?

I am using `@prisma/client@3.15.2`

Here is what I am currently working with:

```js
      const { valid: validFor, expire, state, address, ...safeProperties } = data;
      
      const addressAsUnsigned = address >>> 0; // address is an ip address represented as an integer. It needs to be treated as unsigned 
      const extendBy = newValidFor - validFor;
      const extended = add(expire, { seconds: extendBy });

      const payload: Prisma.DataTableUpdateArgs = {
        where: { address: addressAsUnsigned },
        data: {
          ...safeProperties,
          address: addressAsUnsigned,
          expire: extended,
          valid: authenticated,
          state: {},
        },
      }

      Logger.debug(payload);
      // contains the changes I expect

      const result = await db.dataTable.update(payload);

      Logger.debug(result);
      // result contains the same values as before the update. 
      // And indeed, when I check the database, nothing changed.


      // Something like this does what I want, so there is really nothing complicated going on... 
      await db.$executeRaw`
         UPDATE data_table SET
           expire = ${extended},
           valid = ${authenticated}
         WHERE address = ${addressAsUnsigned}
      `;
```

Hopefully, I have not missed something too obvious.

Comment: Can you show us your schema.prisma part for dataTable model? And do you get an error or nothing happenes?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience,

> 1. Why is the update (using the ORM way) not performed ?

You might be updating the wrong thing. Is your address an @unique field in your prisma.schema?

> 2. Why the value of data.address seems to affect the outcome of the update ?

Prisma might have messed some things up with wrong data. If your data is not unique, you might be updating the first row with that address. If you want to update multiple fields with same address, use updateMany

> 3. Do I have to provide all of the fields of the entity when updating ? Or in this case, could I just put what I want changed inside of data ?

No, you only need to put in the data that you need. In your "where" field, add the unique address, and in your data, only the fields that you are changing. In your case, expired and valid. If you want to skip updating some values, use "expired: undefined" and so on

Since you are using typescript, I would advise you to put your object directly inside the prisma update to get the correct types. (At least to fix this problem)

prisma.dataTable.update({where: {...}})

This way you will get the correct types. There is also a command to list all available args inside (control + space on mac)

[image]

Note that using the spread operator (...) will remove the listed types, so use it last.

Some other things: double check if your prisma import is correct. Is your data correct, is your returned data correct? Did you refresh your database on update? It might be updated but you just need to refresh for new changes.

Comment: Thanks @SlothOverlord for the in depth answer. The ```address``` field indeed has a unique index associated to it, and it is also the only unique index I have on that table. Additionnaly this is happening on a dev database where there only is single record in that table.

As for the completion, I am doing more or less that, I just have that habit of extracting all the properties, minus some prisma sometimes expects to be left out. In this case it is indeed useless.